# Java method type error in simple iteration program

Tags: java, compiler-errors, void

I have been working my way through Think Java by Downey and have gotten quite stuck with a bit of code that uses iteration to print a multiplication table. I tried replicating the program on my own and received a "'void' type not allowed here" error. I thought it might have been some mistake I had made that had caused the error, but I tried compiling the code Downey had provided with the book and received the same compile-time error. Below is the code:

```
public class Table {

  public static void printRow(int n, int cols) {
  int i = 1;
  while (i <= cols) {
    System.out.printf("%4d", n*i);
    i = i + 1;
}
  System.out.println();
}

 public static void printTable(int rows) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= rows) {
      printRow(i, rows);
      i = i + 1;
    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.print(printTable(5));
  }
}
```

If anyone can help me understand what's going on here that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The print statement will never print, Because printTable() doesn't return anything

Comment: So his code is just incorrect... I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to print and just call the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printTable(5); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`printTable` method does not return anything. Instead of calling `System.out.println` in `main()`, you can add the print statement in `printTable` method itself if needed and then just call the `printTable` method from `main()`. I am not sure what you want to print again as the `printRow` is already printing the output.

```
public class Table {

    public static void printRow(int n, int cols) {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= cols) {
            System.out.printf("%4d", n*i);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printTable(int rows) {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= rows) {
            printRow(i, rows);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTable(5);
    }
}
```